# Dynamic Pivot T-SQL Synapse

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am trying to make a dynamic pivot work in an **Azure Synapse** table. I can make it work in MSSQL with the following query (or other queries I saw elsewhere), but when I try to replicate it in Synapse I fail miserably.

Basically, I want to go from this:

To this:

Here's the query I used in MSSQL. It works sans for ordering the columns correctly, which is another problem to solve...

```
create table #temp
(
    columnName varchar(max),
    columnNumber integer,
    cellValue varchar(max),
    rowNumber integer,
)

insert into #temp values ('xxx_(col1)', 1, 'dajkhdjkas', 1)
insert into #temp values ('abc_(col2)', 2, '31209839043123', 1)
insert into #temp values ('yyy_(col3)', 3, 'dddddddddd', 1)
insert into #temp values ('xxx_(col1)', 1, 'cxczxczxcz', 2)
insert into #temp values ('abc_(col2)', 2, '31890839012433', 2)
insert into #temp values ('yyy_(col3)', 3, 'aaaaaaaaaa', 2)



DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(columnName) + ',' FROM (select distinct columnName from #temp ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

print @cols

set @query = 
'SELECT rowNumber, ' + @cols + ' from 
(
    select columnName, cellValue, rowNumber 
    from #temp
) src
pivot 
(
    max(cellValue) for columnName in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
drop table #temp
```

When I try it in Synapse, I get a:

> A variable that has been assigned in a SELECT statement cannot be included in a expression or assignment when used in conjunction with a from clause.

I solve it by changing:

```sql
SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(columnName) + ',' FROM (select distinct columnName from #temp ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end
```

Into:

```sql
SELECT @columns = string_agg([columnName],',')
FROM (select distinct [columnNumber],[columnName] from #temp) tmp
```

After that I get:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Parameter'.

...and this is where I am stuck.

Comment: `'Parameter'` doesn't appear in your SQL at all, which suggests the problem is the value of `@columns`. Why did you drop `QUOTENAME` when you (correctly) switched to `STRING_AGG`? That's *important*. I suspect you have a column with a white space (`' '`) in it, and as a result you end up with incorrect syntax as you are delimit identifying your columns anymore.

Comment: @Larnu, I changed it because QUOTENAME was only returning one name instead of all three after I removed "@cals +" (which was causing the error).

Comment: `QUOTENAME` just delimit identifies the value, @F.R. , so what you're stating doesn't make sense there. So, for example, if you have a column `SomeColumn` with the value `N'My Column Name'` then `QUOTENAME(SomeColumn)` would return the `sysname` value `[My Column Name]`.

Comment: If you re-add `QUOTENAME` it doesn't work, what error do you then get?

Comment: @Larnu, you were right! I had white spaces in my column names. After changed it to 'replace([columnName],' ','_') [columnName]' it started working. But now the max(cellValue) part gives me nulls instead of values for some reason...

Comment: Because that isn't correct. Why are you replacing the white space? Why aren't you using `QUOTENAME` any more? Use `QUOTENAME`. The problem is purely because you removed `QUOTENAME`; put it back in, and the problem is resolved. I'm actually surprised that query didn't error, because of invalid column references.

Comment: @Larnu If I change `SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(columnName) + ','` to `SELECT @cols = QUOTENAME(columnName) + ','` (to avoid the error I mentioned above) it returns one field name instead of all of them. That's why I changed it to `string_agg`.

Comment: You *still* need `STRING_AGG`... `STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([columnName]),',')`. The problem apepars to be more that you don't understand the solution you were previously using, meaning that you don't understand the solution you are using now either. You should really take the time to understand solutions that you have found; the one you are first tried to use uses a documented [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment), so it's actually a good thing that synapse errors.

Comment: Either way, with `STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([columnName]),',')` it works now. You can close the thread.

Comment: if issue resolved post, it as answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(columnName) + ','`

`FROM (select distinct columnName from #temp ) as tmp`

`select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end`

to

`SELECT @columns = string_agg(quotename([columnName]),',')`

`FROM (select distinct [columnNumber],[columnName] from #temp) tmp`

`order by min([columnNumber])`

solved all issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).